# php and ruby working together?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache, cakephp

I am currently buildind a game with a webclient some devices and a REST server giving everyone objects.

Right now, my webclient is written in php with no frameworks, no problems here, rest client works perfectly.  I'm using cakephp2 as a REST server, but i'm new to it, documentation is poor, and the ORM is really strange.

I'm still at begenning, and i want to ship some parts soon. The cakephp2 models and ORM are way too light for me.

My REST server is in one folder of my client website (/API). I know apache ca run ruby, but could it run the same way.

examples :   currently :    my_web_client/API call Cakephp2 on :80.
I wish    my_web_client/API    call a rails on the same port.

Does apache support this ? Can i run my website this way or do i need 2 websites on separate webhosts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about using Ruby on Rails and deploying with passenger.  If these two assumptions are correct, you're in luck, it is possible to have a PHP application running on the same server (and even the same VirtualHost).  Check out [this section](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_passengerenabled_lt_on_off_gt) of the passenger documentation.

Comment: Thanks seem quite incredible. I was ready to go for another webserver alongside to apache. I think i will use this in production. Really really thanks.